# Does xpath explicitly allow undefined variables?

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I was trying to pull some data out of an XML file using xmlstarlet, but

```
xmlstarlet sel -t  -v '//div[contains(@class,'addresses')]/a'
```

was getting me a lot more than I expected.

I finally worked out - with the help of replacing `-v` with `-c` to debug the xpath - that it was because the single quotes around `'addresses'` were vanishing because the whole argument is single-quoted: replacing that with `"addresses"` worked as expected.

What I'm really confused about is quite what `contains(@class,addresses)` does - because xmlstarlet didn't flag it as an error or warn about it, even though I presume it's treated as an undefined variable.

I checked the source in https://github.com/fishjam/xmlstarlet/blob/master/src/xml_select.c but I can't spot a 'warnings' flag - should there be something like that, or are xpaths defined to allow this?

Answer (score 2):

In `contains(@class,addresses)`, `addresses` selects (possible) child elements named `addresses` of the context node (i.e. in `//div[contains(@class,addresses)]` the `div` element the predicate `[contains(@class,addresses)]` belongs to); a variable (reference) would be written as `$addresses`.

Comment: Thanks for the response... but my `div`s didn't hold any `<address>` elements, so why were any `div`s being selected? I'm a bit perplexed that `contains(@class,"address")` means 'if the class attribute contains the word `address`' but not quoting it means something... weird.

Comment: Your question just said you expected an error or warning in terms of an undeclared variable; there was no indication you got something selected you didn't expect to be selected; I think this is an edge case where the definition of contains says for an empty string as the second argument the result is true; and an empty node-set (which e.g. `contains(@class, addresses)` has as the second argument) is converted to an empty string.